# Manage mysql files with nother user

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, user

I need to copy files in /var/lib/mysql/database/* yo another dir with admin user.
File in /var/lib/mysql/database has 660 mysql:mysql

I already add admin user to mysql group, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files using root:

`sudo cp -r /var/lib/mysql/database/ /path/to/destination/here/`

`root` is the only real admin user, all of the other "admin" users on a system just have permission to pretend to be root, but aren't actually admins themselves.